# Populating persistent attributes from transient attributes in Oracle ADF 12.1.3

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am really new to JDeveloper and Oracle ADF. In my use case, the table than my Entity is based on has a primary key that is not auto-incremented. (DB2). Asking the DBA to auto-increment it is not an option right now. Or asking the DBA for pretty much anything, for that matter. Due to no Sequence definition in the table PK, I am unable to use the neat little Groovy Expression to auto-increment. Here is what I tried: -
a) Created a transient attribute called idGenerated in the view object and populated it with an SQL query that finds the maximum value of the pk column.
b) Attempted to populate the ViewObject id Persistent field by using the expression: idGenerated+1.

This causes a null pointer exception as idGenerated ends up null. :(. Is there any way to execute this without resorting to EJB? To be honest, writing EJB class to do this seems to be complete overkill.

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but that sounds like an awful work environment

Comment: Is this a pre-existing table with a fixed schema? If you are able to specify the type of the PK the solution is relatively simple

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Pre-existing table with no way of tinkering with the table. I'm supposed to work-around it in ADF. Ugh

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will work - the value for the Attribute gets set too late (via the query) to be used in the groovy expression.
When I ran into a similar problem I simply extended the EO and wrote custom Java to grab the idGenerated value and increment it in the Getter method for the attribute. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is : add transient attribute in the Entity Object and then add it in the View Object attribute from the entity object. This has helped me most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ADF has a mechanism for generating ids without autoincrement or sequences, check this out: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/multidatabaseapp-085183.html
http://www.adftips.com/2010/10/adf-model-generating-unique.html
http://adfspecialists.blogspot.com/2012/09/adf-bc-primary-key-generation-provided.html